# Reflooring a horse trailer

Tags: structural

What kind of treated wood thats is 1 1/2" thick x 6" or 12" wide will support roughly 300lbs per hoof.

Comment: The supports are on 24" centers

Comment: Talk to a wood supplier. Check on here this has been asked before.

Comment: The problem is horses are not easily figured at lbs per hoof.  a straight load or a slant load. I have one horse that on a slant load would punch through 6-800 lbs per hoof even though he is a draft mix with huge hoofs , I have a mare that may be almost as high because she has smaller hoofs for her size, straight load a bit less maybe 200 per. I have had wood 2x trailers but the wood was tight grained clear and a 3/4 mat over that. That was many years ago I only go aluminum today after wood and steel failures. Only a comment as it will probably be closed, #1 vertical grain treated for rot.

Comment: you need planks? you can't use plywood?  maybe scaffold planks?

Comment: Is that 300 lb/hoof (I like that unit of measurement!) when standing evenly on all 4 feet, or does that include walking when 1 or more hooves are off the ground?

Comment: Now that that's out of the way... [The Sagulator](https://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/) is a good way to calculate shelf loads, and that is, essentially, what you've got - a shelf on 24" supports supporting one or more hooves. Of course, The Sagulator is designed for static loads and you've got a _very_ dynamic load (moving horses, moving trailer, bumps, turns, etc), but it will give you a minimum baseline.